# One public IP address per Namespace

Tags: ubuntu, networking, command-line, ip, network-namespaces

How can I associate one public IP address per Namespace in my Ubuntu 14.04 server? I need to launch one specific process per Namespace then per public IP address.

I want to do that:

configuration:

```
nameSpace1 use: publicIP1
nameSpace2 use: publicIP2
nameSpace3 use: publicIP3
```

Terminal:

```
nameSpace1 ffmpeg etc...
nameSpace2 ffmpeg etc...
nameSpace2 youtube-dl etc...
nameSpace2 streamlink etc...
nameSpace3 ffmpeg etc...
```

Comment: Was also asked on [superuser](http://superuser.com/questions/1175309/one-public-ip-address-per-namespace).

Comment: Yes unanswered like on superuser, thanks a lot dirkt for your usefull helping.

Comment: I answered in the comments: You can't do that unless your ISP gives you several public IP addresses. Which you very likely don't have, unless you are paying a lot of money for it. And please don't ask on different stackexchange sites, only one site per question.

Comment: I understand that you have your rules, apologize for multiple post. Yes I have multiple public IPs, my problem is to associate process with a variable like Namespace and associate this variable with one publique IPs in network configuration. It's unbelivable for me that command-line program which give a simple way to do it doens't exist withtout virtual machines or containers and complexe bridges. A lot off web sites and servers are limited by IPs, automation needs a program which don't virtualize more than networking. I would be gratefull if you have an other way than Namespace.

Comment: You still haven't told us how your ISP provides different IPs, or what your ISP is so we can google for he help pages of this ISP and find out. If you have different network interfaces for each public IP, you can move these interfaces into each namespace. Or you can try to let those programs bind on a specific interface without using a namespace. If you have a VLAN, you can split it up and put it into each namespace with a VETH pair. Etc., etc. There's no  answer possible with the information you've provided so far.

Comment: Ho, my bad. I have a VPS 3 in https://www.ovh.com/fr/ and i bought some IPs but in my head I can do it with proxy servers too, no? I don't know what I have ^^' but I understand that you think I can launch a process with a Namespace and associate this Namespace with a public IP. If yes, it's a good news, I just need to understand how now ^^' (with a pair veth perhaps?). Don't hesitate to tell me what to do to help you to answer :).

Comment: Answered here, very unix specific, please the delete the corresponding question on superuser.

Comment: Please do **not** crosspost. See [Is cross-posting a question on multiple Stack Exchange sites permitted if the question is on-topic for each site?](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/64069)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Partial answer, based on some assumptions that may not be true:

In general, network namespaces provide control over what network interface is visible to what processes. Assigning a network namespace to an interface will make sure it's only seen by processes running in that namespace. Conversely, processes running in that namespace will only see network interfaces in their own namespace.

So there are basically two ways to let processes running in a namespace communicate with the outside: (1) Move an existing network interface connecting to the outside into the namespace using `ip link set`, and (2) make a virtual ethernet pair (a sort of "pipe"), put one end in the namespace, let the other end stay global, and set up routing, optionally NAT etc. for it.

[OVH](https://www.ovh.com) seems to own (at least) the `176.31.0.0/16`, and according to [this help page](https://www.ovh.com/us/g582.configure_an_ip_address_on_a_virtual_machine) and a bit of `whois` sleuthing, they have divided it up into 4096 blocks of 16 IP addresses, where the first and the last four of each block are reserved for internal use. This also means they either have less than 4096 customers who bought RIPE blocks, or they do carrier grade NAT, and you'll be sharing your IP addresses with someone else.

So, if you bought a `/28` RIPE block and got for example the block `176.31.154.160/28`, the 15th address (176.31.154.175) is for broadcast, the 14th address (176.31.154.174) is the gateway, and you can use addresses 176.31.154.161 to 176.31.154.171.

For OVH, a [failover IP](http://help.ovh.com/IpAlias) as added by creating a virtual interface of `eth0`. So I'd assume your 11 usable addresses would be handled in the same way. However, some people [report problems](http://www.webhostingtalk.com/showthread.php?t=1143767) when doing that, which may or may not related to the particular way they are trying to do it. You'll also likely need a [macvlan](http://www.pocketnix.org/posts/Linux%20Networking:%20MAC%20VLANs%20and%20Virtual%20Ethernets) instead of a virtual address interface/label to be able to move it into the network namespace. So by convention, you'll likely and up with `mac0` (long form `mac0@eth0`) instead of the `eth0:0` used below.

Assuming that this is the correct way, whatever is needed to make it work, you'd end up with interfaces `eth0:0` up to `eth0:10` for each usable address. You can then create a namespace (`ip netns add space0`), move the interface into this namespace (`ip link set eth0:0 netns space0`), set up the correct routing in the namespace (`ip netns exec space0 ip route add default via 176.31.154.174 dev eth0:0`), and run your application inside that namespace (`ip netns exec space0 ffmpeg ...`).

If you are just using netspaces and not full-blown containers, handling DNS resolving is a bit fiddly and restricting it to the namespace in my experience doesn't always work (and I haven't found a good way to fix it yet), though I had a very different setup which will probably not apply to your case. So you might experience problems if you are using hostnames instead of raw IP addresses in the applications, but fixing that is probably worth another question.

**Edit**: The more I think about it, the more it seems that the OVH setup with an address block with its own broadcast address is really meant to serve as a means to run multiple VMs: Each VM should get its own IP address (instead of a network namespace), and then you have something like a private LAN where your VMs can communicate with each other. So we're likely abusing the concept quite a bit by using namespaces instead.

**Edit**: Looking at OVH's VPS offers instead of help pages, I see they offer a "13 geolocation and 16 IPs" options. If *that's* what you bought, it again depends how they set this up. I couldn't find any help pages about that, so I assume that information is in the email you received. If you can just assign those IP addresses directly to your `eth0` interface, then the procedure is essentially the same, though you'll probably need different gateways.

Also note if your just running a web server, you can often tell the web server to only bind to a specific IP (or even bind to several IPs, and act differently depending on which IP you are bound to), so you don't need network spaces in this case.

Comment: The gateway (perimeter router) IP address can be assigned arbitrarily within the subnet.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling: If you actually know how OVH handles multiple IP addresses in their various optional offers, I wouldn't mind some specific information, instead of me having to guess it.

Comment: I don't know how OVH assigns IP addresses, but unless you do, a blanket statement saying that out of a 16-address block "the 14th address is the gateway" is potentially misleading at best.

Comment: Thank you really much for your answer dirkt you are my hero. I wanted also to test it with http://freeproxylists.net/fr/ to don't overspend for IPs. To this case: how OVH assigns IP address count too?

Comment: @MichaelKjörling: That's from the [link](https://www.ovh.com/us/g582.configure_an_ip_address_on_a_virtual_machine) I gave, not a "blanket statement". And yes, they reserved the 14th address for the gateway, etc., all as I described. Yes, in general you don't need to do it that way, but they did.